# Associating Swift things with NSObject instances

Tags: generics, swift, nsobject

I'd like to associate Swift things (generics, structs, tuples, anything Objective-C doesn't like)  with NSObject instances via extensions.

How can we do that today? `objc_setassociatedobject` is of no use to deal with Swift features.

My first approach was to use a global dictionary with weak keys to store the associations. Something like:

```
struct WeakKey<T where T: NSObject> : Hashable {
    weak var object : T!

    init (object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return self.object.hashValue  }
}

func ==<T where T: NSObject>(lhs: WeakKey<T>, rhs: WeakKey<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.object == rhs.object
}

typealias ThingObjcDoesntLike = (Int, String)

var _associations : [WeakKey<NSObject>: ThingObjcDoesntLike] = [:]

extension NSObject {

    var associatedThing : ThingObjcDoesntLike! {
        get {
            let key = WeakKey(object: self)
            return _associations[key]
        }
        set(thing) {
            let key = WeakKey(object: self)
            _associations[key] = thing
        }
    }

}

let o = NSObject()
let t = (1, "Hello World")
o.associatedThing = t
```

Unfortunately this crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the `_associations` declaration. Removing the `weak` solves the crash, but would cause NSObject instances to be retained.

In order for this to be viable we should also set the association to `nil` when the NSObject is dealloc-ed. We can use an associated witness object for that, and override its dealloc to do the work. For simplicity's sake, I'm leaving that out from the code above.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
class ObjectWrapper : NSObject {
    let value: ThingObjcDoesntLike

    init(value: ThingObjcDoesntLike) {
       self.value = value
    }
}

extension NSObject {

    var associatedThing : ThingObjcDoesntLike! {
        get {
            let wrapper = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, someKey) as ObjectWrapper?
            return wrapper?.value
        }
        set(value) {
            let wrapper = ObjectWrapper(value: value)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, someKey, wrapper, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! That appears to work, but are there any guarantees that `objc_setAssociatedObject` can deal and manage memory properly of the wrapped pure Swift constructs (super structs, generics, etc.)?

Comment: It doesn't have to. It only worries about retaining/releasing the container object (which follows normal objc conventions). The container manages the memory of the construct inside it.

Comment: It appears there is more to it than it looks. When using this I started getting strange memory errors. I ended up doing something else which I'll post later.

Comment: `ObjectWrapper` doesn't need to subclass `NSObject`

Comment: also, this way you must write a new class and new `NSObject` property for every `ThingObjcDoesntLike` type you need to use

Comment: @newacct not at all, you just make ObjectWrapper accept a generic type <T>

Comment: @NickLockwood That would make ObjectWrapper generic, and cause a crash. Better to use `Any`.

Comment: @NickLockwood: According to the Xcode release notes, "A generic class can define a stored property with a generic type, as long as the generic class is not made available to Objective-C"

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I guess you might be able to handle it with a double-wrapper (an object exposed to objc that contains an object that isn't exposed to objc) but that's starting to get awkward.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the memory errors I got when using this initially, so it might have been another thing. Still, I'm a bit wary of accepting this solution just yet. It'd be great to have some official confirmation from the documentation. For now, +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

@NickLockwood's answer *should* be the right answer. However, when using his approach I started to get strange memory exceptions on run time. It might have been another thing, but the problem disappeared when I tried another approach. Have to dig further.

Here's what I did in Playground form. I'm posting it because it appears to work and I find the code interesting, even if it ends up not being the best solution.

I'm using a global Swift `Dictionary` with pointers as weak keys. To clear the dictionary, I use a witness associated object that calls back the object with the association on `deinit`.

```
import Foundation
import ObjectiveC

var _associations : [COpaquePointer: Any] = [:]

@objc protocol HasAssociatedSwift : class {

    func clearSwiftAssociations()
}

var _DeinitWitnessKey: UInt8 = 0

class DeinitWitness : NSObject {

    weak var object : HasAssociatedSwift!

    init (object: HasAssociatedSwift) {
        self.object = object
    }

    deinit {
        object.clearSwiftAssociations()
    }

    class func addToObject(object : NSObject) {
        var witness = objc_getAssociatedObject(object, &_DeinitWitnessKey) as DeinitWitness?
        if (witness == nil) {
            witness = DeinitWitness(object: object)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(object, &_DeinitWitnessKey, witness, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }
}

extension NSObject : HasAssociatedSwift {

    var associatedThing : Any! {
        get {
            return _associations[self.opaquePointer]
        }
        set(thing) {
            DeinitWitness.addToObject(self)
            _associations[self.opaquePointer] = thing
        }
    }

    var opaquePointer : COpaquePointer {
        return Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()
    }

    func clearSwiftAssociations() {
        _associations[self.opaquePointer] = nil
    }
}

let o = NSObject()
o.associatedThing = (1, "Hello")
```